# Password protect pdf file generated in Stata

Tags: stata

I am preparing to feedback individual level results to study participants. I am able to generate a report for each participant after running a chunk of code in stata that ends in outputting a pdf file. Is there a way in Stata of including a password so that the pdf report can only be opened using a password known to the individual participants e.g. their study number? Or do I have to use an external program to automate this process?
Thanks!

Comment: Hey, a little more detail may help you get a better answer. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for guidance.

Comment: Consulting `help putpdf` and [Stata Reporting Reference Manual](https://www.stata.com/manuals/rpt.pdf) will be a useful place to start; however, you'll see that the answer is no (though there may be a user-generated program for this).

Comment: However, you can "use an external program" to password protect from within stata. See this example from Statalist: https://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2009-05/msg00916.html